# Who is "the blaspheming foe" of Maoz Tzur?

Tags: history, chanuka, song-poetry, curse

In the song [Maoz Tzur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%27oz_Tzur) it says

> לְעֵת תָּכִין מַטְבֵּחַ מִצָּר הַמְנַבֵּחַ -

which the [OU translates](http://www.ou.org/chagim/chanukah/maoz.htm) as -

> When You will have prepared the slaughter for the blaspheming foe.

Who is this blaspheming foe of which we sing?

Answer (score 3):

It probably refers to Edom, who is described in the last verse. In that verse, our salvation from Edom is written in future tense, as a prayer.

It may instead refer collectively to all 5 exiles described in the song, of which Edom is the last. After our final redemption, we will dedicate the 3rd beit hamikdash.

I don't think it refers to each exile individually, since it would take a little bit of gymnastics to explain how we dedicated the *mizbeach* after both Bavel and Persia.

Comment: Indeed Rav Efrayim Greenblatt includes a running explanation of the song in [_siman_ 170 of _Riv'vos Efrayim_](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_1083_162.pdf) by someone named Nechemya Nusbecher, in which he says that that line is a reference to a verse in _Y'shayahu_ (35:6) about _Edom_.

Comment: @WAF, cf. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12400.